# Rails creating role hierarchy with devise and enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, enums

i am working through with a light weight app that i want to implement a super simple role structure. currently i am working with enum to set the role, but i want to implement some sort of hierarchy.

```
enum role: [:registered_user, :active_registered_user, :admin, :account_admin, :vip]
after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

def set_default_role
  self.role ||= :registered_user
end
```

This is how i define the roles on the users model, what i would like to do is have it so that registered_user < active_registered_user < admin < account_admin < vip.

So pretty much they have access to all the roles beneath them.

So if something said `if current_user.admin?` if i was an account_admin or vip it would return true.

I was thinking of doing some thing like this

```
def has_access?(user, access_role)
  access_hash = {
    "vip" => ['vip', 'account_admin', 'admin', 'active_registered_user', 'registered_user'],
    "account_admin" => ['account_admin', 'admin', 'active_registered_user', 'registered_user'],
    "admin" => ['admin', 'active_registered_user', 'registered_user'],
    "active_registered_user" => ['active_registered_user', 'registered_user'],
    "registered_user" => ['registered_user']
  }
  access_hash.[user.role].include?(access_role)
end
```

But then i have to run this method everywhere! is there a more ruby way of doing this?

Any help or design insights will be much appreciated.

**Note:**

enum allows for some cool active record calls:

```
user.admin! # sets the role to "admin"
user.admin? # => true
user.role  # => "admin"
```

just if you wanted to see how i called user.role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums map to a real number value. So perhaps something like:

```
def access_level
  self.class.roles[role]
end

def do_a_thing_only_admins_can_do(user)
  return unless user.access_level >= 2
  do_thing
end

def do_a_thing_only_vips_can_do(user)
  return unless user.access_level >= 4
end
```

Note: It's probably a better idea in the long run to use something like [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to manage authorization.

Comment: That being said, I would recommend to assign the enums a value. This way, you have more clear control over your roles. Otherwise, you may accidentally shift the roles as new ones are added.

Comment: Thank you kindly! i like that approach. i was going to use Cancan, but it seems like overkill for such a small app